# Why do we need long type?

Tags: types

*long* uses 8 byte and *float* also use 8 byte. But *float* can represents all the values of *long* and has a more wider range than *long*.
So, why do we need *long* type?

Comment: It's a matter of precision.

Comment: Float cannot *exactly* represent all values of long.

Comment: Why vote -1 for my post   - - !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the fact that long and float, as you pointed out, are both 8 bytes long. That means that they can both represent exactly the same number of values - namely, 2^64 distinct values.

As you said, float can represent a much wider range of values than a long can. Therefore, it follows that float must not be able to represent *every* value along that range. Floating point numbers are an approximation.

For example, long might be able to represent 100, 101, and 102 while float might only be able to represent 100 and 102. These are just examples, but the concept holds true - float can not represent, exactly, every value along its range.

The two data types are "interpreted" differently. The bits "00110101" translate to one number if it is a long, and a completely different number if it is a float.

You can read the full details about longs and float in the Java Language Specification:

Integer Types: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1

Floating Point Types: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3

Comment: But 101 equals 1.100101 * (2 ^ 6) in binary. I suppose 101 can be represented by float?

Comment: I got your idea. For example, if the frac part of float was 4 bit, the float then couldn't represent 1000001. Is it right?